# Multi-computer connection LAN via Ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, connection

Our teacher gave us 4 PC's at school . I want to setup a LAN connection between them all for file sharing via Ethernet cables, and no internet access is available or needed. I have successfully connected the first two with a simple cross-over cable, but I am lost on how to connect all 4. Because I won't use internet, I assumed that I won't need a modem either, am I wrong?

1. Should I use a modem/router?
2. How do I? Without internet, that is.

---

**EDIT:**

So according to what Paul said, I should just plug in the Ethernet into the hub/router, but all the computers tell me that the cable is not connected, while on the hub I see that it has not detected the computer either.

In short, the devices are only detecting the cables.

Note: Each PC has one NIC

---

**EDIT 2**

The router is on, but shows no response at all. But I think it is wrong setup. I just connected to power, but someone told me that I need a telephone cable into the wall even if no internet is needed.

Comment: All you need is an Ethernet switch (each PC connects to the switch in a star configuration) and assign a unique (private) static IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.x)  to each PC.

Comment: Are you using crossover cables?

Comment: @RonTrunk No I am using straight ones ( I checked the colour pattern test)

Comment: So none of the PCs show a link?

Comment: @RonTrunk Yes, On each PC in the networking&sharing center I see (LAN2, not connected) and on the router there is really no response at all.

Comment: Your advice that a telephone cable needed to be connected into the wall is incorrect.  It may be that your router is faulty, or configured in a not-so-common way.   I would try taking the 2 computers which talk together, plug them in via the router and see if they work.  Do it so you test between all 4 ports. If this works, the router is OK hardware wise.  You would then try factory reset the router, then the computers (or for the computers, just renew their DHCP leases).   Alternatively to resetting the router, statically assign all computers IP's in the same subnet.

Comment: Note: If you have ports plugged into the router and PC (and the PC and router are on, of-course), you would expect a light on the router indicating the port is in use.  If this is not happening, junk the router.

Comment: I agree with @davidgo. It sounds like your router is bad.

Answer (score 10):

You won't need a modem but you will need a (cheaper) device called a hub or switch. For your purposes a router is a more sophisticated device than you will need, but it should also work.

Plug a cable from each pc to the hub/switch/router. Usually it would be a straight patch cable, not crossover (aka twisted), but most hubs/switches/routers will auto-sense and work with whatever you plug in.

Comment: Should also work with a router if that's all you have, answer updated.

Comment: The answer will give the physical connection. How to get the pcs to talk to each other will depend on what operating system you are using. But provided the pcs do not have wildly different settings, what you did to get sharing working for 2 using a crossover cable should be good for the 4 once they are physically connected.

Comment: But the PC and the hub can't detect the other end. (we found a working ethernet hub)

Comment: The hub won't detect anything, and can't be detected, it's a dumb physical device. You said you had 2 pcs successfully connected using a crossover cable? Plug both those pcs into the hub. They should work exactly the same as before. If not, either the hub or one or both off the cables isn't working. If it's an old hub that can't cope with crossover cables, make sure you are using patch (not crossover) cables. Also check you have lights on the hub and pc sockets when you plug it all together. Report back if that doesn't work, we'll get on to the 3rd and 4th pcs once the first 2 are working. :-D

Comment: I see from your edit that by 'detected' you meant the link light on the socket. In that case confirm correct cables.

Comment: Also, you stated that you found a working hub - how did you verify it was working?

Comment: @TGamer - happy to go to a chat if you'd like?

Comment: Yeah I can explain better in chat

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple possible answers to this. But let me start with one basic part. If you only have one NIC per computer then you need a device to connect all four to. This is called a switch. Many 'modem' and 'routers' are in fact multiple devices in one box. The four ports on the LAN side usually act the same as a regular cheap switch.

You then have this setup:

```
                    [switch]
                   |  |  |  |
                  /   |  |   \
                 /    |  |    \
       Computer 1     C2 C3    Computer 4
```

To connect an end device (the computer) to a switch you use a normal ethernet cable.
To connect two similar device (PC direct to another PC, or switch to switch) you would use a crossover cable.

Note that most modern switches include auto MDI/MDX and will auto matically compensate for the wrong cable. As do all gigabit switches.

Lacking a switch or a device which includes a switch you can do something with at least two network cards in each PC, forming a ring. Or one network card per other PC (so 3 NICs per PC in this case). [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/955019/10gbe-win8-1-file-sharing-between-3-pcs-without-a-switch) shows a nice diagram on on how that was done with 3 PCs. (Ignore the internet part).

I mention that for completeness sake. This is not something you will need in most cases.

That answers the part about the physical connection.

Net up if the configuration. How you do that depends per OS, but assuming TCp/IP you want to give each computer a different IP address. And since you want them to communicate give them an IP in the same network range.

The easiest way for a small setup is to do that manually. E.g.

- On PC 1 set IP 10.0.0.1 with netmask 255.255.255.0
- On PC 2 set IP 10.0.0.2 with netmask 255.255.255.0
- On PC 3 set IP 10.0.0.3 with netmask 255.255.255.0
- On PC 4 set IP 10.0.0.4 with netmask 255.255.255.0

That will put all PCs in the network part 10.0.0.x. They can talk to eachother. You are done.

Alternatively you can set up a DHCP server on one of the PCs or on a 'very capable switch' (read: a SOHO router will do) and set all the PCs to DHCP. This means the PCs will ask there network to give them all the needed information. You will have to put the answers to this in the DHCP servers configuration.

The latter is more work and for a simple setup I would skip it. But it scales a lot better and when you get to dozens of PCs this is the way to go.

Lastly, read [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) on our sister site serverfault. It explains a lot of the background.

Comment: Your post is very helpful, but the problem is that none of the PC's can detect the switch.

Comment: Even with regular cable? (you mentioned a router which ususally has 100mbit ports. And those need not be MDI/MDX capable. So a crossover cable will fail. Said cable will work when directly connecting PC to PC, but it will not work when connecting PC to router. You can test that by plugging both ends into the router. If the port LEDs light up you have a crosscable).

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a switch / router. Hub are last centurie's things.
Each PC should be connected to the switch with a straight cable.

Then you have to go to network connection and set static IPs for all the 4 PCs in the same network. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) (bad source, but simple enough concept) to see what's a subnet.
You may need to disable Windows firewall too.

BTW: Modern NICs do not need crossed cables to connect two PCs anymore, they negotiate and configure their NIC's ports properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your lan cards and cables on workability.

   a. Check that your LAN connection actualy works on all PC, connect each one of them between each other(if you have that much time to test 100% connection is ok)

   b. Check your LAN configuration on each PC, so they must be in one network and share same mask
   example IP: / example MASK:

   192.168.0.101   255.255.255.0
     192.168.0.102   255.255.255.0
     192.168.0.103   255.255.255.0
     192.168.0.104   255.255.255.0

   no DNS or gateway needed
2. Then plug all of the LAN cables from PC's to the switch/hub (most modern switches do not care how you cross patch your cables as long as they are the same in configuration)

OR

You can do steps **1 and 2** then put all cables into ROUTER, after that configure router to enable DHCP on it and set all your LAN configuration on PC's to Auto.

If there are still problems and your 1 and 2 steps are ok, see that you OS configuration with network has shared files enabled for local network (Its home network for XP and W7)